# Spanish TTS on VS 2015 with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text-to-speech

I need to have Spanish text to speech functionality in my winforms application. This is to develop a system to help native Spanish speaking kids to read and write.
I've searched through Microsoft page how to install a Spanish voice and I found this file, which I installed: MSSpeech_SR_es-MX_TELE.msi

I installed it and now what do I do? I searched through the references in "add reference" in Visual Studio and I did not find anything new. The English voices work fine, I can simply do "voice.Speak("Hello"); and that's it, that simple, but what do I do now to install and use other languages?
I'm doing a Windows Forms project in Visual Studio Community 2015 with C#. It only needs to speak a few words at a time, not really recognize speech to start.
Thank you.